# Is it possible to specify a starting number(float number) for an ordered list?

Tags: html

I want to start the numbering as a float number for an ordered list.
In my below code it starts with a int number.

```html
 <ol type="1">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Now I want to start this with "1.1". I have tried with start value 1.1 , but it is not working.
Is there any way to do this?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [counters](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#counter) to do so:

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```